# hibernate is inserting null values in foreign key field with apache-poi

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi

I have 2 simple domain objects as follows..with Oracle database

```
@Entity
@Table(name="rfpobject")
public class Rfpobject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

private String ide;
private String unit;

private String rfpid;

private String requestid;

private String incoming;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "rfpid",cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Set<AspsortObject> rfpide;
```

The second object is :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="aspsortobject")
public class AspsortObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "rfpid")
    private Rfpobject rfpid;
    private String requestid;
    private String aspart;
    private String aspname;
    private String asporganisation;
    private String aspsort;
```

the method  save at database :

```
    @PostMapping("/upload")
     public void addaspsort(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException
     { 
         ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(0);        
         FileInputStream f =  (FileInputStream) file.getInputStream();
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(f); 
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); 
            Row row;
            for(int i=1; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){ 
                 row = sheet.getRow(i);
                  System.out.println("aspsorttt");
                 AspsortObject aspsort =  new AspsortObject();
                 Rfpobject rfpid = new Rfpobject();
                rfpid.setRfpid(row.getCell(0).toString());
                 aspsort.setRfpid( rfpid);
                 aspsort.setRequestid(row.getCell(1).toString());
                 aspsort.setAspart(row.getCell(2).toString());
                 aspsort.setAspname(row.getCell(3).toString());;
                 aspsort.setAsporganisation(row.getCell(4).toString());
                 aspsort.setAspsort(row.getCell(5).toString());
                 aspr.save(aspsort);
            }
        }
    }
```

For some reason hibernate is inserting null values in foreign key field of rpfid in my models.AspsortObject. I tried changing cascading styles, generation strategies, but nothing worked. Making nullable=false throws error . Data gets inserted but in AspsortObject.rfpid  the values is null please help me

Comment: This most likely has nothing to do with Apache-POI rather with Hibernate mapping being incorrect. I remember having the same issue, I'll check my test project and post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd save the Rfpobject first, get its id and with that I'd save the AspsortObject.

I remember struggling with this myself as I thought I can save both at the same time and hibernate can do everything for me which I still think is possible but I can't remember the solution from the top of my head.